# URL invalid error whenever calling from twilio

Tags: twilio

I want to make an application which can make a call to other peoples using Twilio in vb.net. whenever i am passing the URL parameter it is showing me invalid URL error. I have made a service which is returning Twimil response. And i am passing this the service URL as a parameter to Twilio URL to Initiate a call.

Not Sure is it the correct way to make call from vb.net

```
Twilio callvar to = new PhoneNumber("+917715*****"); 
var from = new PhoneNumber("+1*********"); 
var call = CallResource.Create(to, from, 
    url: new Uri("demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml")); 

service public class Service1 : IService1 
{ 
    public void GetDataJSONFormat() 
    { 
        var response = new VoiceResponse(); response.Say("Hello Shrikant");       
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code of what you've tried so far

Comment: Hi, I'd love to help out here, but we do need an idea of what you've done so far. If you could share the code you're using, that would really help.

Comment: Twilio Outbound call:

Comment: Twilio callvar to = new PhoneNumber("+917715*****");
            var from = new PhoneNumber("+1*********");
            var call = CallResource.Create(to,
                                           from,
                url: new Uri("http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"));
                                           //url: new Uri("http://localhost:59491/Service1.svc/data"));

Comment: service  public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public void GetDataJSONFormat()
        {
            var response = new VoiceResponse();
            response.Say("Hello Shrikant");
            
        }
 }

Comment: Added code from comments

Comment: Your code doesn't look like vb.net but you can find an example on how to make a call in c# here https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls?code-sample=code-make-an-outbound-call&code-language=cs&code-sdk-version=5.x